# Load pages between navbars

Tags: html, css, html5-canvas

I have a header navbar, footer navbar & a slidebar created using slidebars.js.The basic structure is somewhat like this:

```
<div canvas="container">

<!-- Header -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark fixed-top">

</nav>

<!-- Sidebar -->
<div off-canvas="id-1 left overlay">

</div>

<!-- Footer -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark fixed-bottom">

</nav>

</div>
```

So the question is how to load pages between these 2 fixed navbars.I've never worked with canvas before but slidebar.js requires it.When I open a simple div inside the main div, jquery doesnt load html pages inside it.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking. Is your sidebar not working, or are you trying to add content to your main body?

Comment: @ObsidianAge I am trying to add content to main body between the 2 navbars.But when I create a simple div inside the main div with an id say '#main' & try ('#main').load(mypage), it does not work.